# Unable to get background image working, could NodeJS be the problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h1>Hello, world! (index.html)</h1>
      <input id="userName" type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Name">
      <button id="clickMe" type="button" name="button">Click Me</button>
      <h2 id="personName"></h2>
      <h2 id="personStatus"></h2>
      <h2 id="personOccupation"></h2>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h1{
  color: red;
}

section {
  background-image: url("../coinflip.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

I have tried the above code and:

```
background-image: url(../coinflip.jpg);
background-image: url(/coinflip.jpg);
background-image: url("/coinflip.jpg");
```

I don't understand why it's not working.

The only thing I can think of is that it has something to do with Node.js

It is my first time trying to learn it, so maybe my server.js file is causing problems?

In the server.js file I have

```
switch (page) {
case '/css/style.css':
      fs.readFile('css/style.css', function(err, data) {
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });
      break;
```

But the switch case is working for all the other pathnames, so I'm really not sure

Comment: `case '/css/style.css':` — So where's the case for the background image? You have to handle **all** the URLs. (Don't reinvent the wheel. Use Express.js and its static module).

Comment: The reason that I'm not using express is that this is part of a course and in this module we are using straight Node to learn and in the next module we'll use express. hmm, so is a missing url here the problem? I thought that the background image would be included through the css url. I have all of the other urls, do you know how I would format the image url in the switch case?

Comment: Why would the background image be handled through the CSS URL? You wrote `background-image: url("../coinflip.jpg");` not `background-image: url("/css/style.css");`. It has its own  URL.

Comment: "do you know how I would format the image url in the switch case?" — The same way as you handled the other URLs (at least in theory, you seem to have failed to provide `content-type` response headers).  The source you are on sounds dreadful if it hasn't covered that before asking you to do this.

Comment: Like I said this is my first time ever working with node, my understanding of how it works is not strong yet. so would i need to do a case like. ```case 'coinflip.jpg': fs.readFile('coinflip.jpg', function(err, data) { res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image'});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();```

Answer (score -1):

If the file is in the same folder, you have to use:

“./coinflip.jpg”

If the file is outside of the current folder (go back folders), you have to use:

“../coinflip.jpg”

I would try the first option, and also would fix it on your node.js.

Comment: "If the file is in the same folder" — the question shows that they are not

Comment: "If the file is outside of the current folder (go back folders), you have to use" — They said they tried that already.